# How to publish list of executable packages in ccnet without zipping it

Tags: package, cruisecontrol.net, publisher

I have ccnet and project configured on it which generates around 7-8 big packages i.e exe which is around 1GB space. I want to list down them on ccnet dashboard. I find this http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Package_Publisher on ccnet website but problem is it creates zip file of all which is what i dont need as I already have installer and that is not what our customer need. Any help in this regard? Earlier I though to let it be zipped and unzip on target server but that takes lot of time as files are huge and I just want to lost on dashboard and let it be just copied without zipping.

Answer (score 0):

To just copy files somewhere else you can use the build publisher. See: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Build_Publisher